# In Windows 10, is Technical Preview the same as Consumer Preview?

Tags: windows, windows-10-preview

I've just installed the Technical Preview of Windows 10. However, the name confused me as in the Windows event they called it the Consumer Preview. When I go to the Windows Insider Program, I can only find information about the Technical Preview. Will the Consumer Preview come later on or is this the same thing?

Comment: At this time Microsoft has made no public plans to release a `Windows 10 Consumer Preview` what was released most recently was the `Windows 10 Technical Preview 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the Consumer Preview come later on or is this the same thing?

There is no such thing as *Windows 10 Consumer Preview*.  There is only *Windows 10 Technical Preview* and *Windows 10 Insider Preview*.

> A public beta version of Windows 10 branded as Windows Technical
>   Preview (later known as Windows Insider Preview) was released on
>   October 1, 2014;

Builds released after April 29, 2015 were labeled as **Insider Preview**.  All builds before that date where the **Technical Preview**.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10)

Answer (score 0):

Technical Preview and Consumer Preview are different. Unfortunately Consumer Preview supposed to be released on 21 st of January but is delayed.

Comment: So, they said they would release the Consumer Preview on 21st of January but actually they released the Technical Preview and delayed the Consumer Preview?

Comment: Technical Preview has been released last year (about October). Last Friday 23rd they released New build 9926 which still is Technical Preview. I am guessing they will continue updating Technical Preview instead releasing Consumer Preview.